# Form load and filter question

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm doing a search form. On top, there are several comboboxes for users to choose a combination of criterias. Then I construct a Where string to filter a sub form displaying the results.

```
Me.sub.SourceObject = "subResultType_1"
Me.sub.Form.Filter = strWhere
Me.sub.Form.FilterOn = True
```

This code is in the "Search" button's click event.

The problem is, when `Me.sub.SourceObject = "subResultType_1"` is executed, the subform will display all the records. Then it gets filtered. But what I want is the subform displays nothing until it gets filtered. This is because my program will be used as front/back end on the rather slow network.

PS: I think when a SQL clause with the WHERE part, or a form with filter, it gets filtered on the back end. So only a little amount of data will be transmitted on the network to the front end. If I'm wrong on this, tell me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is one that I often use, which is to save the subform with a recordsource that produces one blank, uneditable record. The SQL I usually use is something like this:

```
  SELECT TOP 1 Null As Field1, Null As Field2, 0 As Field3
  FROM MyTable;
```

This displays one blank record with Nulls for some fields, 0 for others (as appropriate). I find it cosmetically more attractive than the alternative.

When I'm ready to display a filtered set, I change the Recordsource instead of setting a filter.

Comment: What I did now is most like your solution: I added a 'blank' filter to the subform: id='', instead of a blank recordsource.

Comment: The difference with mine is that yours returns no rows, whereas mine returns on non-editable blank row. I think it's better to display the rows, as it helps the user understand what they are going to see when they perform a search, whereas a blank row does not (nor does an empty subform control, which is why I don't use that approach, either).

Comment: Another problem, when I do like this, set a 'blank' filter or recordsource, the next time I use this form, it memorize the filter of last time, not a blank one anymore ... How to prevent it from memorizing it?

Comment: Yes it's a problem, I did just like you said, but after some use, I found out that the recordsource of the subform is changed to some SQL clause that I have used. How can I fix the recordsource for a subform?

Comment: If you don't want to persist the recordsource change, then don't save the design change. Filters are different, in that Access automatically saves them whether you tell it to or not, so I tend to set the filters in the OnLoad event of the form when I'm worried about persistent filters.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force users to filter the form before showing any results, don't bind the SubForm to the query (leave the form's `RecordSource` empty) and do it in code instead: you can simply set that in your Search button click event:

```
Me.Sub.RecordSource = "subResultType_1"
```

Nicer still, make the Subform invisible (set its `Visible = No` property in Design mode) and show it once the user clicked Search:

```
Private Sub btSearch_Click()
  Me.Sub.RecordSource = "subResultType_1"
  Me.Sub.Visible = True
End Sub
```

If you want to do more complex filters, you can also do something like:

```
Private Sub btSearch_Click()
  Me.Sub.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM subResultType_1 WHERE " + strWhere
  Me.Sub.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Something like this would allow you to construct complex `WHERE` queries from code based on a bunch of input from the user.
For instance, you could have multiple textboxes where the user can enter information relative to particular fields to narrow downs the search.

You then construct the WHERE clause from the content of these textboxes, like this:

[image]

That becomes this once the user has entered some filtering criteria:

[image]

Comment: If things are slow, you do not even have to load the form into the subform control until it is required.

Comment: Thanks.. I like your theme. And the list you make, is a continuous form?

Comment: @darkjh: thanks. The main form is a single form with a header. The data is in a subform displayed as a datasheet. I'm using Access 2010, so theming is pretty nice.

Comment: Ok it's 2010, so I don't need to blame myself for the ugly interface i made... I read your blog, nice! We got some things in common: foreigner in foreign country and make Access Apps...

Answer (score 2):

You said "*my program will be used as front/back end on the rather slow network*".

What is your back end storage database?  Is it an Access (Jet/ACE) database file?

If yes, you should be aware than networked Access databases are really only suitable on a fast, reliable, hard-wired LAN.  If any of the following conditions are true, you should change your data storage to something other than Access.

1. wide area network (WAN)
2. wireless network connection
3. wired connection to an unreliable local area network (LAN)

The common risk in those situations is that a dropped connection can corrupt your Access database.  It may not happen at every dropped connection, but eventually you **will** corrupt your Access database.

Comment: It's wired networks. But the factory here doesn't have serveurs. All the network is located in the headquarter 300 kms away ...

Comment: @darkjh Sounds like a WAN, and that's not suitable for Access.  But your Access application can work fine if you move the data storage to a client-server database, and change the table links to ODBC to the server.  If your organization will not allow that change, make sure you have a reliable backup strategy to minimize the risk of data loss when the Access back-end gets corrupted due to a dropped connection.

Comment: You know it's in a big company. To get access to those server for using SQL SERVER, my boss have to pass many administrative files ... So Access just perfect for this reason: simply put it on the shared storage and it acts like a server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question there. The where clause will filter the query on the SQL server.

[Access SQL: WHERE clause](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-sql-where-clause-HA010278156.aspx)

Comment: My back end is also a accdb file.. So i'm wandering where the query gets filtered. But it seems what I guess is right.

Comment: If the back end is ACCDB/MDB, the filtering happens on the local workstation, as it must, given that there is no server on the other end. That doesn't mean it's slow or inefficient, though -- caching can do an awful lot to speed things up.