# Access 2000 form is slow to load over a network

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access 2000 database that sits on a peer to peer network. (All computers are connected via ethernet 100 to a simple 4 port switch)
The database is designed with a back-end and a front-end.
There are 2 users that connect to the back-end via the network. One user connects to the back-end directly as the back-end sits on her computer.
All the computers are fairly low spec, with either 500 meg or 1 gig of ram

I have one form, frmInvoice, which is based on the table "tblInvoice" There are about 60,000 records in the table. There is also the table "tblInvoiceProducts" which is linked to "tblInvoice". There are about 150,000 records in the table "tblInvoiceProducts".

When I open form "frmInvoice" on the computer which hosts the back-end, the form opens very quickly. However if I open the form on one of the other computers it is very slow to open. However, once opened, record navigation is fast.

I think the problem is that when the form is opened, Access opens the entire table and all the records are accessible. Am I correct in this assumption?

I need to rectify this problem and welcome all suggestions.

I am going to install a D-Link DNS-323 2-Bay Network Storage Enclosure and store the back-end database on this as this will improve security / data protection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I disagree with the close vote because this question touches on an issue basic to database programming ... not just Access Jet/ACE, but any database.

Comment: Are your tables properly indexed and have PK, and does your form contain any filter ? You could also consider opening the form in Add mode when it applies. 4 users and 150,000 records seems ok for Access! Is your switch a real switch or a simple hub ?

Comment: Do you have a SORT ORDER defined on this form? If so, and it's not sorted on the PK, that's going to force a lot more data to be pulled, because it won't know which record is the first one until it's sorted all the data.

Answer (score 6):

"*I think the problem is that when the form is opened, Access opens the entire table and all the records are accessible. Am I correct in this assumption?*"

My bet is you are absolutely correct.

If you open the property sheet for the form, choose the Data tab, and look at the value for Record Source, do you see the name of one of your tables?

Or a query without a WHERE clause, perhaps like "SELECT * FROM tblInvoice;"?

If your answer is yes to either of those questions, Access will have to pull every single record from the table across the wire.

So, **don't do that**!  :-)  The key to decent performance is to limit the form's Record Source to a reasonable subset of rows.

Choose some criterion which makes sense in your situation, perhaps invoice date, and build a query which incorporates that criterion into its WHERE clause.  Base that criterion on an indexed field --- add an index if your table doesn't already have one on that field.  You can experiment by creating a new query in the query designer ... maybe the SQL View would look like this:

```
SELECT Invoice_ID, Customer_ID, invoice_date
FROM tblInvoice
WHERE invoice_date = Date();
```

That would retrieve only rows where invoice_date matches today's date.

(If you've already loaded the form, pulling down all the rows into local cache, you won't get a true indication of the speed of that query.  It would be better to test the query from a new Access session without first loading the form.)

So then give the user a method to select a different invoice_date.  For example, a text box control named txtSelectDate.  And in the After Update event of that control, you can write an updated SELECT statement which you apply as the form's Record Source.

```
Private Sub txtSelectDate_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strSql As String
    If Len(Me.txtSelectDate & "") > 0 Then
        strSql = "SELECT Invoice_ID, Customer_ID, invoice_date" & vbCrLf & _
            "FROM tblInvoice" & vbCrLf & _
            "WHERE invoice_date = " & Format(Me.txtSelectDate, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
        Debug.Print strSql
        Me.RecordSource = strSql
    End If
End Sub
```

The Debug.Print line will print the SELECT statement in the Immediate Window so if anything goes wrong you can view the completed statement, and copy & paste it into SQL View of a new query for testing.  Changing the Record Source property automatically causes Access to requery the data source.  And you can validate the user's entry in the text box's Before Update event to make sure it's a valid date.

Another possibility is to have the form first load with a single non-editable dummy record([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383904/form-load-and-filter-question/6390247#6390247)).  Then display records only after the user chooses an invoice_date.  To do that, you could use something like this as the form's Record Source:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Null AS Invoice_ID, Null AS Customer_ID, Null AS invoice_date
FROM tblInvoice;
```

Comment: limiting the data using a WHERE clause has certianly helped

Comment: But is is SIMPLY NOT TRUE that binding a form to a whole table pulls the whole table across the wire. That's only true if you page through the data and that requires displaying all the data pages. Rushmore only pulls the data that's needed, which for a newly-opend form bound to a table is a few KBs of data (the PK index and the first few data pages). Now, in the background, it may be prefetching more data, trying to anticipate your next request, but it won't simply brainlessly pull the whole table.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent suggestions made by HansUp, I would add the following:

- Detailed forms should never take more than a couple of seconds to load. If they do, you're either doing something wrong or you need to optimize your binding/code.
  Datasheet and reports can take longer depending on their complexity and how often people need them. Basically, if it's something they need a lot, it need to be fast. On the other hand, if it's a monthly report, waiting 30s is acceptable.
- You don't say if your front end is split from the back-end or if you're using the same .mdb for your data and UI. If you do, then stop and [split your database](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-01.html), even for the person on the same computer as the data.
  Your back-end mdb file should only contain your data tables, and nothing else. The front-end mdb must be installed on the user's individual machines.
- Make sure that your tables have the right indexes for your filter and sorting criteria. If you're binding your form to your tblInvoice and set the property to order by invoice reference and your table doesn't have an index for this, Jet will need to load all invoice references from the table to check their order.
- If all your indexes are OK, Access will *not* load all the data to display a single record in a detailed form. It will only load lots of data if you're using a datasheet or a continuous form.
  So the issue is probably with something else: maybe you're binding to a complex query from within your form, like a combo box or a datasheet, that it's that particular thing that's dragging your down.
- Try to bind/unbind controls one by one to see which one has the biggest impact, then concentrate on optimizing that particular area.
- You can also bind the controls as needed from code. For instance you can keep your form or the expensive controls unbound and wait for the user to select the record they need before you bind it to the form/control.
- If you have lots of information on the form that loads related data from other queries and tables, you could re-design the form to group data in a Tab Control, then have a sub-form in each tab-control to display the data and load this only the user selects the tab.
- Make sure that if you display lots of data in continuous forms/datasheets, that they are bound as snapshot to make them read-only. If they are read/write and someone else is trying to load a detailed form, Access has to do extensive lock check to make sure that the data is not being edited in multiple places. The more you make your data read-only, the better.
- A final tip for for better performance: create a dummy table with a DUMMY field in your backend, link to it from the front-end. Bind this table to a form that has a single control for the DUMMY field. Make this form invisible and open it automatically when you start your application.
  This form will keep the dummy table open and will ensure that your front-end doesn't have to open/close the connection to the backend every time it needs to query it.
  Locking the database is time-expensive, especially over the network. If this is done very often, it can really decrease performance.
  Maybe it won't change anything for your particular case, but I've found it to be good practice as the impact can be tremendous.

Comment: The OP also says that one user connects to the back-end directly.

Comment: Hmm ... I read that as she has both front and back end on her machine, so her copy of the front end connects directly to the backend, whereas the other users' front ends connect over the network to the backend.

Comment: @HansUp: I wasn't completely sure how the OP uses his Frontend, I added this point to make it more explicit for other reader's benefit as well.

Comment: Well, I was sure *until* I saw Craig's interpretation.  :-)  I certainly agree, it's an important point for any multi-user application.  I'll discard that comment; you already know I felt your answer deserved an upvote.  :-)

Comment: Thanks Renaud. Very concise and imformative. I will follow your suggestions closely

Comment: I'm not at all sure about the comment about datasheets/continuous forms -- Rushmore operates for those just as it does with a single form (i.e., retrieving the rest of the recordset in the background). You can see Rushmore in operation if you open a form and there is no value for the N of "Record 1 of N" -- that value won't happen until the entire recordset has been retrieved (at least, the PK index -- the actual data pages likely won't be retrieved until needed). This is the case with all forms, not just datasheet/continuous forms.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reasons for forms being very slow to load.
They include:
1. Having active filters on the form
2. Having combo boxes which allow users to navigate / select records

If I remove these I don't experience and speed issues.

To allow users to navigate / select records, I have a cmd button on the form. When clicked it opens a pop up form allowing the user to select the record of choice. I store the record id as a variable, close the pop up form and filter the recordset of the form e.g
select * from tblInvoice where InvoiceId = tmpInvoiceId

works for me!

Answer (score -5):

yes Access (Jet) sucks bad across a network.. to make things more complex, there aren't real 'indexing tools' in Access like there are in SQL Server..

If I were you, I'd go get ONE solid PC, install SQL Server 2008 R2 on it, and upgrade to Access Data Projects.

Comment: which version of SQL Server 2008 R2 would I need?

Comment: From the requirements, the tables only contain a few records. Throwing a SQL Server instance to solve a performance issue that it obviously more related to the implementation of the application rather than the database is not particularly wise. SQL Server comes with its own sets of issues, higher maintenance, higher requirements, and its' not going to solve any problem if the app itself is not fixed. Understand the problem first: try to solve it in the app, THEN move to SQL Server if you really need it, but for such a small app with a handful of users, it's unlikely that it makes much sense.

Comment: Don't listen to him. SQL Server isn't a silver bullet that will magically solve your DB performance problems.

Comment: Not going to go the SQL Server route. Thanks for the suggestion but I think I need to fix the form!

Comment: Access Data Projects have not had any improvements since Access 2000.  I fully expect MS to remove that feature in a future version of Access.

Comment: I'm not certain. The Access team sought out feedback from SQL Server users just around the time A2010 was shipping, so I'd expect something to happen with that. But with the investment in Sharepoint, I wouldn't be surprised if the work went into making SQL Server easy to use via Sharepoint, rather than with a revival of the ADP. Actually, there were changes/improvements in ADPs in both A2002 and A2003, some of which in A2003 reverted bugs that had been fixed in A2002.